# Jenkins failing due to an error could not transfer artifacts to central artifactory

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, bitbucket

Scenario:

Builds run fine when using the already cached dependencies. However, when updating the version of Selenium 3 to Selenium 4 or for any other dependencies, I am getting the following error of build failure.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXX: Could not resolve dependencies for >project XXXl:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at >org.testng:testng:jar:7.5: Failed to read artifact descriptor for >org.testng:testng:jar:7.5: Could not transfer artifact org.testng:testng:pom:7.5 >from/to central (artifactory link): Connect to artifactory failed: Connection >timed out (Connection timed out)

Tried updating settings.xml, updated settings.xml in bitbucket and gave the file path, and added settings.xml directly in Jenkins manage.

If this has happened to anyone, please let me know your ideas on resolving it.

Answer (score 0):

> Connect to artifactory failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)

You have a network issue between maven and artifactory.  Talk to those who set up this scenario.